# nodejs server returns error on first attempt

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I want to setup a remote file serving through server, so I code this script:

```
var http = require('http'),
express = require("express"),
mysql = require('mysql'),
t = false,
request = require('request'),
app = express(),
connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'xxx',
  user: 'xxx',
  password: 'xxx',
  database: 'xxx'
});
app.get('/files/:hash/:title', function(req, res) {
  var hash = req.params.hash;
  connection.query('SELECT * from table WHERE hash="' + hash + '"', function(err, rows) {
    t = rows;
  });
  if (!t) {
    res.writeHead(400, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('token expired');
  } else {
    var lastItem = t.pop(),
    urls = lastItem.url,
    cookies = lastItem.cookies,
    options = {
      url: urls,
      headers: {
        Cookie: cookies
      }
    };
    req.pipe(request(options)).pipe(res);
  }
});
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(500, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
  res.end('prmission denied');
});
app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server running');
```

I returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` on first attempt, after refresh page again, it works perfectly, can anyone please check the code where is the issue ?

Comment: check `rows.length`

Comment: Looks like your typical every day asynchronous logic failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: that sql code doesn't look very safe.

Comment: the timeline of events doesn't quite match your code... the first call should be giving you a 400 instead. i suspect somewhere else in your code you're also using `t`, setting it equal to something other than `false`...

Comment: `rows.length` returns 0 on first attempt

Comment: sometime it returns 400 error too

Comment: in your current implementation, each request will use the previous request's hash. Not necessarily from the same user.

Comment: without a previous request, there are no cookies with that hash  ...suspect you want the `if (!t) {...}else{...}` in your callback, and use `if(rows.length)` instead of `if(rows){...}` (or equivalently `if(t){...}` in your current code).

Comment: @Kevin, pointed that out 15 minutes ago in my (downvoted) post...

Comment: BTW, probably returns a 400 error when you wait long enough.  "on first attempt" is probably really your first attempt that returned a response.  The thing I think you're missing is that the callback in the second argument to `connection.query(...)` is not evaluated until after the `if (!t) {...}else{...}` has already been evaluated.

Comment: by using `if(rows.length)` it returns `    if(rows.length){
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: rows is `undefined` when err is not `undefined`, so be sure and check the value of `err`.  Gotta run, so I won't be able to help any more on this today...

Answer (score -1):

I suspect it's that this callback:

```
 connection.query('SELECT * from table WHERE hash="' + hash + '"', 
    function(err, rows) {t = rows; });
```

is evaluated on the next tick of the event loop, whereas, this line:

```
urls = lastItem.url,
```

is evaluated in the current scope, so you're always returning data from the previous request (which is a strange behavior).   On the first query, I'm guessing there are no rows in your table with the current hash, which is why `t.pop()` is `undefined`.  (note that an empty array is truthy which is why `if(t){...}` executes even though the number of rows is zero)

Comment: I agree that this is your every day asynchronous logic failure, but why the down vote?

Comment: yeah you are right, I'm not familiar with node js logic, I'm newbie, It doesn't return data from SQL, thats glitch, how can I make it working ?

Comment: I did, i don't see it as being useful. It simply points out the problem without presenting a solution. though.. i doubt you could provide a solution that hasn't already been provided at the duplicate.

Comment: Ok, everyone has their own standards, but helping to clarify the source of an error is often quite helpful...

Comment: @KevenB  BTW, Thanks for the downvote (seriously). It's good to remember that a reference to a well asked and answered SO post is probably better than and incomplete answer.  On that note, I think your downvotes would be better received as guidance if you regularly commented (maybe just cut/paste) something like "Downvoted this answer because a link to better answer would been more helpful".